# apis.live.net/v5.0 - How to validate token on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-storage, live-sdk, microsoft-live-connect

I have a resource (REST) server (written in Java/Spring) that I need to validate a Microsoft token from a client.  I need to:

1. Check that the token is valid for my app
2. Get the token's email address and lookup that user in my app (I can do this)

I currently use Google, Facebook and am adding Windows auth.

For Google, I check my token at:

> https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token={accessToken}

For Facebook, I use:

> https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token={accessToken}&access_token={appId}|{appSecret}

What do I use for live?

> https://apis.live.net/v5.0/????

I need something that returns my app id so I can make sure the token was created by my app.

I can get the user info from the token just fine (the URL is `https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token={accessToken}`) but it does not allow me to verify that the user is for my app that is registered.

What is the token validation scheme here?  It's not a JWT token, because it does not have any '.' characters in it...

According to this https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview:

> Access tokens issued by Azure AD are base 64 encoded JSON Web Tokens (JWT).

However, when I try to base64 decode my token, it is binary.  `https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me` shows that it's a valid token, though.

Here is an expired token:

> 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